# Biggest sum of value for n stairs with value and use the given step

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a staircase with `n` stairs each containing an integer value, e.g.,

```
staircase = [11, 22, 44, 5, 12, 34, 55, 45, 23, 64]
```

and given a set of possible step sizes for the staircase, e.g.,

```
possible_steps = {3,4,5}
```

I want to find the sequence of steps in order to maximize the sum of collected values. A value is collected once you step on a stair.

**Example:**

`step_sequence` is `[3,4]`  , value is `44+55 = 99`

`step_sequence` is `[4,4,4]`  , value is `5+45+(out of index is 0) = 50`

The best `step_sequence` is `[3,4,4]` which maximizes the collected values (`44+55+64 = 163`)

Question:

How can I use dynamic programming to solve the problem? Or is the best way to solve the problem with dynamic programming?

Comment: I tried for 5 minutes now , but I cannot make sense of the question. It seems you want to maximize the value collected when going up a stair. How are steps used? What constraints do you have? What does "we can pass the end directly" mean?

Comment: Yes the question is to find the maximize of the collect values , with the given steps [3,4,5]  \n  And sorry about the "we can pass the end directly". It means the steps allow not end with the last  stair .

Comment: Do I understand correctly that given the stair and the steps, you want to find the order of the steps which maximizes the collected values? And from your examples it seems that reusing steps is also allowed.

Comment: Yes , find the step order  to get the maximizes the collected values.

Comment: Ok that makes sense now. I suggest you revise your question accordingly because no one wants to read the comments to understand the question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Is this homework? You should label it as such.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share **your** findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can solve it using dynamic programming. If `n` is the total amount of numbers in the staircase and `m` is the number of possible steps, then the solution will have time complexity `O(nm)` and space complexity `O(n)`. The idea is to ask yourself what is the best sum I can get when the stairs are ending at index `i`. Kinda similar to the coin change problem.

```js
function maxSum(stairs, steps) {
    let dp = [], maxSteps = steps[0], globalBest = undefined
    for (let i = 1; i < steps.length; i++)
        if (steps[i] > maxSteps)
            maxSteps = steps[i]
    for (let i = 0; i < stairs.length; i++) {
        let best = undefined
        for (let j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
            if (i - steps[j] == -1 && (best === undefined || best < stairs[i]))
                best = stairs[i]
            else if (i - steps[j] >= 0 && dp[i - steps[j]] !== undefined &&
                    (best === undefined || dp[i - steps[j]] + stairs[i] > best))
                best = dp[i - steps[j]] + stairs[i]
        }
        dp[i] = best
        if (best !== undefined && i + maxSteps >= stairs.length &&
                (globalBest === undefined || globalBest < best))
            globalBest = best
    }
    return globalBest
}

console.log(maxSum([11, 22, 44, 5, 12, 34, 55, 45, 23, 64], [3, 4, 5]))
```

There are some special cases, like when entering the stairs `i - steps[j] == -1` or when checking if we can reach the end of stairs for the global max `i + maxSteps >= stairs.length`. The rest is pretty much standard dp.

This implementation also works with negative numbers on the staircase (the steps have to be positive). It is assumed you have to collect at least one number on the staircase, if that is not possible the function returns undefined.